# JavaScript Alert not working properly

Tags: javascript, php

I am showing an alert using javascript in my php page. It is not showing alert box. Kinldy guide me how to make it work fine

```
if($sql && $sql2 && $sql3) 
{
    echo "<script> alert('Deleted successfully!');</script>";
        $myURL = 'students_list.php';
        header('Location: '.$myURL);
        exit;
    else
{    
echo "<script> alert('Temporary problem, try again!');</script>";
}
?>
```

It is deleting data from database but not showing alert. Tell me how to make it work fine.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to another page or to send a page with JavaScript on it? You can't do both.

Comment: I see no database actions here. Any console errors? What you see in source? And your header will not work, because there is output already

Comment: Check the `if` condition is working

Comment: You dont close your If-Statement } <- missing

Comment: @Quentin i am trying to pop up a alert box when this script runs and after clicking ok it redirect to $myURL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this

```
<script> alert('Deleted successfully!');window.location='students_list.php'</script>
```

like this when the alert is closed you redirect.

Answer (score 3):

You are first trying to display an alert:

```
echo "<script> alert('Deleted successfully!');</script>";
```

then to issue a HTTP redirection:

```
$myURL = 'students_list.php';
header('Location: '.$myURL);
```

These functions are incompatible, because of the way HTTP redirects work:

- If you have output buffering enabled, a redirection response (HTTP 302) will be generated, along with your alert script as body... however the body of redirects is ignored by browsers supporting them (i.e., all of them, except for example a `curl` without the `-L` option).
- If you don't have output buffering enabled, the script will output the JS code for the alert, but could not output the redirection anymore because at that point HTTP headers have already been sent out. Depending on the settings, a warning will be displayed in the client's browser.

A possible solution for that is to issue no redirect and use JavaScript to redirect the client, something like:

```
echo "<script>\nalert('Deleted successfully!');\n";
echo "location = 'students_list.php';</script>";
exit;
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this it works perfectly

```
<?php
    $sql=1;
    $sql2=2;
    $sql3=3;

if($sql && $sql2 && $sql3) 
{       
    echo "<script> alert('Deleted successfully!');window.location='students_list.php'</script>";

        exit;
   } else
{    
echo "<script> alert('Temporary problem, try again!');</script>";
}
?>
```